# Cannot disable Azure Machine Learning Schedule because of 'Provisioning' state

Tags: azure, azure-machine-learning-service

There is one Schedule that we are not able to disable on our Azure Machine Learning workspace:

```sh
az ml pipeline disable-schedule --schedule-id SCHEDULE_ID \
                                --resource-group RG \
                                --workspace-name WN
```

It's been returning:

```
(BadRequest) Cannot update an entity while it's in Provisioning state.
```

We were able to disable other schedules on the workspace without any issues.
Has anyone faced a similar issue?

Answer (score 0):

The key component that is responsible for the scheduling of the job had experienced spurious outages that led to the schedule being not completed when those outages occurred.

The cause for those outages was identified and fixed. you can retry and we will keep monitor on this. If you want to be unblocked with the effected instances please raise a support request in the azure portal.